King war fortune teller magic
This was a film I saw as a child. I don't exactly remember the plot but a soldier becomes king after king's death, and the death was rather comical. Then one day he wishes to select his queen from a bunch of ladies and falls in love with a fortune teller. There even was an intimate scene of her asking him to select out of the cards and something. Later there was some cruel lady who did some sort of magic on him to get kingdom or become immortal (don't remember exactly). I saw the movie around 2002 on a tv broadcast by star-movies
Does anyone know the name or producer?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Are there any other details that might help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Feel free to add anything else you might remember into the question.

Kull the Conqueror, (1997), with Kevin Sorbo.  The cruel lady with magic was played by Tia Carrere.  

While they speak, a messenger from the palace reports that the king
  has gone mad and is slaughtering his heirs.
Taligaro and the Legion ride for Velusia, Kull following behind. They
  enter the throne room to find the king covered in blood and the floor
  littered with bodies. The king turns on Taligaro, but Kull stops him,
  trying to calm his blind rage. The king then turns on Kull instead.
  Mortally wounded when his own sneak attack fails, the king summons
  enough energy to make Kull his heir out of spite.

Kull isn't selecting his queen from a bunch of ladies, he is looking over the old king's harem.  The fortune teller (Karina Lombard) is among them.

Aw crap. I wanted to write that as an answer but wasn't sure enough about it. Well anyway, +1 of course.
